# jQuery 1.8 outer Height/Width not working

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-1.8

I have used `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` on many places. Now, after jQuery 1.8 was released I have met a lot of issues caused by object return instead of its size.

For example:

```
$('#stackoverflowdiv').Height()      // returns 100 px
$('#stackoverflowdiv').outerHeight() // returns "stackoverflowdiv" div
```

The only thing that I have found to fix this was to use "true/false" in the function as follows but the I get the same results as the standard `width()` and `height()` functions:

```
$('#stackoverflowdiv').outerHeight(true)  //  returns 100 px
$('#stackoverflowdiv').outerHeight(false) //  returns 100 px
```

Has anyone knew why this is not working any more or other way to get the height/width of element + its margins.

EDIT: I started to believe that this is caused because I am selecting elements in iframe using `contents()` function. I will try to make a demo.

Comment: Does your element have a margin? If not it's correct, that both values are the same.

Comment: Your question tells us nothing about what value is expected.  Please include your HTML & CSS.  Also set up a demo to show how jQuery 1.8 is working improperly as compared to previous versions.

Comment: There is no way to show my code. It is composed from many js/css/classic asp files. I will try to make an exmaple with iframe and hope this happens again.

Comment: This seems to be a very localised issue to your code as jQuery's 1.8 height/width methods are behaving as expected. If anything, the 1.8 release added new features to those methods and addressed/fixed several issues. See some tickes on fixes for 1.8: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10877 , http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10413 , http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724 , http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11724

Comment: This issue is beacuse a old version of jquery-ui

Comment: @ Andrés Ricardo Torres Martínez So, if I update my jquery-ui version it should be fixed?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, as in outerwidth / height broken and returning an element, not the numbers. this question should not be closed. good job moderators.

Comment: new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718084/jquery-1-8-noncurrent-jquery-ui-outerwidth-and-outerheight-broken/12718222

Comment: This should not be closed

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is actually a **known jQuery bug** that you can read about [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12159).

I'm experiencing it with no parameter and the fix is setting the parameter (even though there's a default {false}), but I was able to break Barlas' fiddle by replacing the true parameter with 1 and false with 0. So don't do that if you are.

Do this:

```
alert(jQuery(this).outerHeight(false));
```

Don't do this:

```
alert(jQuery(this).outerHeight());
alert(jQuery(this).outerHeight(0));
```

Comment: I had this problem with JQuery Tools Tooltip plugin when upgrading JQuery from 1.7.2 to 1.9.1. After changing `outerWidth()` to `outerWidth(false)` and `outerHeight()` to `outerHeight(true)` it works fine.

Comment: I've encountered this issue when the jquery-tokeninput started rendering the dropdown in the wrong place. I traced it back to an outerHeight method and was able to resolve it by passing false.

I also tried removing jquery-ui-1.8.20 and that also fixed the issue - I will now upgrade jquery-ui and see if it is the interaction between it and newer versions of JQuery. In my case the jquery-tokeninput broke after upgrading to JQuery 1.8 and above.

Answer (score 5):

It only works if I do `.outerHeight(1);` not `.outerHeight(true);`

Answer (score 2):

JQuery 1.8 `height()`, `innerHeight()`, `outerHeight()` and `outerHeight(true)` work as expected:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVq5H/) - Working height methods

The demo above is using a div:

```
<div id="myDiv">My Div</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Using this script:

```
var $div = $("#myDiv");
var height = $div.height();
var heightWithPadding = $div.innerHeight();
var heightWithPaddingAndBorder = $div.outerHeight();
var heightWithPaddingAndBorderAndMargin = $div.outerHeight(true);

var $result = $("#result");
$result.append("height: " + height);
$result.append("<br />height with padding: " + heightWithPadding);
$result.append("<br />height with padding and borders: " + heightWithPaddingAndBorder);
$result.append("<br />height with padding and borders and margin: " + heightWithPaddingAndBorderAndMargin);
```

Resulting in the following:

```
height: 20
height with padding: 30
height with padding and borders: 32
height with padding and borders and margin: 52
```

Answer (score 2):

The best fix is to pass the Boolean parameter `true` or `false` when calling `outerHeight` or `outerWidth`

**But..**

If by any chance you don't have access to files which calls `outerHeight` or you don't want to edit all `outerHeight` functions in your files, you can override the jQuery `outerHeight` function like below to make it always pass the `true` parameter

```
var oldOuterHeight =  $.fn.outerHeight;

$.fn.outerHeight = function () { 
    return oldOuterHeight.apply(this, [true]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine mate, i can't be sure without seeing your html and css but you can inspect [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/47Kt6/7/) and examine it is working fine on jQuery 1.8.0

[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/47Kt6/7/)

**jQuery:**

```
console.log($('#stackoverflowdiv').outerHeight(false));//returns 110
console.log($('#stackoverflowdiv').outerHeight(true));//returns 130
```

**css:**

```
#stackoverflowdiv { 
      height:100px; 
      margin:10px 5px; 
      padding:5px; 
      border 2px solid #fff;
}​
```

Are you sure that you forgot use a semicolon or define `document.ready` ? Or worse forgot to define `margin` or `border` ?

Answer (score -2):

`outerHeight` only returns an integer or `null` according to the [jQuery DOCs](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).

> Returns the height of the element, including top and bottom padding,
>   border, and optionally margin, in pixels. If called on an empty set of
>   elements, returns undefined (null before jQuery 3.0).

There must be something else in your code futzing with your output and making you see the div element.

Comment: I suppose this could be result because I am selecting element in iFrame using contents() function. I will make a test with this.