# jQuery 1.8.2 + noncurrent jQuery UI = outerWidth and outerHeight broken

Tags: jquery, version, outerwidth

This is a re-do of a question that was closed erroneously: [jQuery 1.8 outer Height/Width not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093806/jquery-1-8-outer-height-width-not-working)

I'm hitting the same issue. `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` and now returning the jQuery object instead of numbers.

We are using jQuery UI 1.8.17, released Jan 10, 2012. It is not a super old version so I have a feeling other people will see this. We are locked into this version because of some terrible jQuery ui plugins, so upgrading is not currently an option.

If I find a solution I will answer this question.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem http://jsfiddle.net/delvarworld/yxDHu/ (jQuery UI version added in "manage resources")

Update: It's because this line in jQuery UI:

```
return orig[ "outer" + name ].call( this, size );
```

is erroneously triggering this condition in jQuery 1.8.2:

```
var chainable = arguments.length && ( defaultExtra || typeof margin !== "boolean" ),
```

because even though `size` is undefined, the check is for `arguments.length`. chainable should be false here. You can pass in undefined and it will still make arguments an object with length 1. Someone needs to read up on their JS ;)

Comment: Bug opened: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12647

Comment: +1 for reopening the question. according to http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ `includeMargin` is an optional parameter, but if not set to true/false it still (jquery 1.8.3) returns the element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution seems to be just passing in `false`

```
$(document.body).outerWidth(false);
```

Or, true if you want the margins, but if you were passing in true it looks like you would not have encountered this bug.

Comment: This seems like a crude solution. I'd have to modify every outerWidth/outerHeight call in every single jQueryUI plugin to pass false when true isn't already there. The real problem is that jQueryUI's overridden methods aren't designed well enough (as of the OP's version). Thus, the proper solution should modify jQueryUI's extension with smarter logic -- fix the problem instead of its symptoms.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it is jqueryUI issue. Seems to be fixed in 1.8.22.

`With jquery UI 1.8.21:` http://jsfiddle.net/yVq5H/13/

`With jquery UI 1.8.22 (fixed):` http://jsfiddle.net/yVq5H/14/

Comment: I had the problem with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.17 - which caused the Foundation Orbit slider to not slide. Took me a while to figure out outerWidth() was broken - an upgrade to the latest jQuery UI 1.10.0 fixed this issue.

Comment: Agreed. Via http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12293 :
"Please upgrade jqueryUI to 1.8.22, as that's the one that's compatible with jQuery 1.8"

Comment: I concur with rkallensee -- this has been a huge pain to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest upgrading both your jQuery and jQuery UI packages. 1.8.1 and 1.8.2 in particular address issues related to outerWidth / outerHeight, and jQuery UI of course needs to be kept in sync.

See the changelogs on the announcements for reference:

http://blog.jquery.com/

http://blog.jqueryui.com/

Comment: cannot upgrade as per question. as jquery is supposed to be backwards compatible, this is an issue

Comment: If you read the blog - jquery 1.8 had issues with outerWidth / outerHeight. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/ Try upgrading jquery itself to 1.8.2 and see if that helps.